# Is it possible to create print preview page of wave dashboard in vf page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, einstein-analytics-dashboards

Is it possible to create print preview page of wave dashboard in vf page and save it as pdf from vf page. in the below code entire page is breaking and loosing its background color.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="true">
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page { size: landscape; }
        div {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        }
        
        iframe {
        border: none;
        width: calc(100% + 16px);
        height: calc(100% + 16px);
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandlink styleClass="cButtons" value="Print" reRender="dummy" onclick="printMyPartialPage();"/>
        <wave:dashboard dashboardId="0FK57000000KzKbGAK"
                        showTitle="false"
                        height="1800px"
                        width="100%"
                        showHeader="false"
                        rendered="true"
                        />
    </apex:form>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>
    <script>
    function printMyPartialPage(){
        window.print();
    }
    </script>
    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What do you mean the entire page is "breaking"?  what specific problems or errors are you seeing?

Comment: specific problem is .. page is loosing all background graphics in print priview...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are referring to?